# MDX Query - Non Empty on 1 Axis

Tags: mdx

I am trying to eliminate a null value from a result set. I am querying only first level dimension data to add to my selection box.

There is a #null value that gets returned with the query.

```
select {} on columns, 
NON EMPTY{[Markets].[All Markets].Children}) on rows 
from [SteelWheelsSales]
```

And the above query does not work since its not against any measure. But i want only the list Markets in the first level to be displayed in my selection box.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `NON EMPTY` try `NonEmpty`:

```
SELECT 
{} ON 0, 
NonEmpty([Markets].[All Markets].Children) ON 1
FROM [SteelWheelsSales];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering instead,

```
SELECT 
    {} ON COLUMNS,
    Filter( [Markets].[All Markets].Children, not IsEmpty ( [Measures].[Sales]) ) ON ROWS
    FROM [SteelWheelsSales];
```